# Flutter order of execution: build and initState

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a preferences menu where I have three settings (e. g. 'notifications') stored with Shared Preferences. They are applied to SwitchListTiles.

Everytime my settings tab is selected there is an error (I/flutter (22754): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/material/switch_list_tile.dart': Failed assertion: line 84 pos 15: 'value != null': is not true.) appearing just a millisecond. After that the correct settings are displayed. This happens when I don't add a default value to the variables initialized in 'ProfileState'. If they have a default value the error disappears but the switches are 'flickering' at tab selection from the default value to the correct value in Shared Preferences.

My assumption is that my loadSettings function is executed after the build method.

How can I solve that? Any help is appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ProfileState createState() {
    return new ProfileState();
  }
}

class ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  bool notifications;
  bool trackHistory;
  bool instantOrders;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadSettings();
  }

  //load settings
  loadSettings() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      notifications = (prefs.getBool('notifications') ?? true);
      trackHistory = (prefs.getBool('trackHistory') ?? true);
      instantOrders = (prefs.getBool('instantOrders') ?? false);
    });
  }

  //set settings
  setSettings() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('notifications', notifications);
    prefs.setBool('trackHistory', trackHistory);
    prefs.setBool('instantOrders', instantOrders);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 8.0),
              child: new Text("General", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)),
            )
          ],
        ),
        new SwitchListTile(
          title: const Text('Receive Notifications'),
          activeColor: Colors.brown,
          value: notifications,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              notifications = value;
              setSettings();
            });
          },
          secondary: const Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.brown),
        ),
        new SwitchListTile(
          title: const Text('Track History of Orders'),
          activeColor: Colors.brown,
          value: trackHistory,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState((){
              trackHistory = value;
              setSettings();
            });
          },
          secondary: const Icon(Icons.history, color: Colors.brown,),
        ),
        new SwitchListTile(
          title: const Text('Force instant Orders'),
          activeColor: Colors.brown,
          value: instantOrders,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState((){
              instantOrders = value;
              setSettings();
            });
          },
          secondary: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward, color: Colors.brown),
        ),
        new Divider(
          height: 10.0,
          ),
        new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Divider(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 20.0),
              child: new Text("License Information", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)),
            )
          ],
        ),
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0) ,
          child: new RichText(
            text: new TextSpan(
              text: "With confirming our terms and conditions you accept full usage of your personal data. Yikes!",
              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to solve it with the recommended FutureBuilder from Darek's solution. The initial error is solved now but now I face another inconvenience. The tab builds itself completely everytime a switch is tapped which is clearly noticable. Furthermore the switches don't run smoothly anymore. On startup of the app you can also see the waiting message shortly which isn't that pretty.

Here is the new class in the code:

```
class ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  bool notifications;
  bool trackHistory;
  bool instantOrders;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    loadSettings();
  }

  //load settings
  Future<String> loadSettings() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    notifications= (prefs.getBool('notifications') ?? true);
    trackHistory = (prefs.getBool('trackHistory') ?? true);
    instantOrders= (prefs.getBool('instantOrders') ?? true);
  }

  //set settings
  setSettings() async {
    prefs.setBool('notifications', notifications);
    prefs.setBool('trackHistory', trackHistory);
    prefs.setBool('instantOrders', instantOrders);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var profileBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
      future: loadSettings(), // a Future<String> or null
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return new Text('No preferences');
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Text('Loading preferences');
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ');
            else
              return new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 8.0),
                          child: new Text("General", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    new SwitchListTile(
                      title: const Text('Receive Notifications'),
                      activeColor: Colors.brown,
                      value: notifications,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState(() {
                          notifications = value;
                          setSettings();
                        });
                      },
                      secondary: const Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.brown),
                    ),
                    new SwitchListTile(
                      title: const Text('Track History of Orders'),
                      activeColor: Colors.brown,
                      value: trackHistory,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState((){
                          trackHistory = value;
                          setSettings();
                        });
                      },
                      secondary: const Icon(Icons.history, color: Colors.brown,),
                    ),
                    new SwitchListTile(
                      title: const Text('Force instant Orders'),
                      activeColor: Colors.brown,
                      value: instantOrders,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState((){
                          instantOrders = value;
                          setSettings();
                        });
                      },
                      secondary: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward, color: Colors.brown),
                    ),
                    new Divider(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 20.0),
                          child: new Text("License Information", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Container(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0) ,
                        child: new RichText(
                            text: new TextSpan(
                                text: "With confirming our terms and conditions you accept full usage of your personal data. Yikes!",
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                  ]
              );
        }
      },
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      body: profileBuilder,
    );


  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lifecycle of a [State](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) object goes `createState` -> `initState` -> `didChangeDependencies` -> `build` (see the linked doc for more details). So in your case it's not an ordering problem. What's actually happening is that `loadSettings` is getting called, but as soon as it hits the `await` a `Future` is return and execution of the caller continues (see async/await in the [Dart docs](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async)). So, your widget tree is being built and your initially null values are being used, then the async part gets executed and your variables are initialised and `setState` is called triggering the rebuild, which works fine.

What you need to use is a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) so that you can build the UI accordingly when the Future has finished:

```
new FutureBuilder(
  future: _calculation, // a Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Press button to start');
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Awaiting result...');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        else
          return new Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
  },
)
```

In the above example, you'd replace `_calculation` with `loadSettings` and return the relevant UIs in the `none` and `waiting` states (the latter will be your one with the `SwitchListTile`s).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it out and it solved my initial error. Now I face some inconveniences. I edited my post with the new code. I would be very happy if you review it and help me out again.

Comment: You need to memorize the Future so that you're providing the same instance each time. This process is well explained in this blog post: https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem of your Edit, store the Future from the loadSettings call in your initState and use this Future for the Future Builder. What you are doing now is calling the function loadSettings everytime your UI rebuilds.

```
class ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  bool notifications;
  bool trackHistory;
  bool instantOrders;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  Future<String> loadSettingsFuture; // <-Add this

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    loadSettingsFuture = loadSettings();// <- Change This
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var profileBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
        future: loadSettingsFuture, // <-- Change this
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   ...
   ...
```